# Safari 6's show/reveal in Finder stopped working

Tags: macos, finder, safari

The other day Safari 6's "Show/Reveal in Finder" command in the downloads window suddenly stopped working. Whether right-clicking or clicking the magnifying glass/loupe button, I can't get the Finder to jump immediately to the file in question. Double-clicking to open the file works, but I don't want to do that immediately with all my downloads.

What can be done about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's caused by the [Apple Events bug](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2012/10/04/aesendmessage-bug-in-mac-os-x-10-8-2/) in 10.8. It also affects other applications and makes Archive Utility stop responding when extracting archives.

As a workaround, you can terminate the appleeventsd process from Activity Monitor or by running `sudo killall -kill appleeventsd` (without -kill the process is sent a TERM signal, which makes other processes stop responding).

Comment: I'll try that when I get home.

Comment: That has fixed quite a few issues! 

Comment: I put it in a script I call fixevents.sh with the command `killall -v -KILL appleeventsd Dock`